# Can't parse out text that is behind </span>text</a> in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I think I have tried it all, read crummy, read documentation on Beautifulsoup4 website. I can't get this thing wrapped around my head.

So to the question:

```html
<a class="ellipsis" href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/5246/investor-a">
<span class="flag small SE"></span>Investor A</a> 
<a class="ellipsis" href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/5247/investor-b">
<span class="flag small SE"></span>Investor B</a>
```

I only want the text behind `/span> "text" <a/>`.

This is the code:

```
def scrape(self):
    self.get(const.StockPicks)
    html = self.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    StockPage = soup.find_all("div", class_="orderbookListWrapper")
    StockNameBook = []
    for StockPages in StockPage:

        StockName = StockPages.find_all("a", class_="ellipsis")
        StockNameBook.append(StockName)
        print (StockNameBook)
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Your question is unclear - what **exactly** is your expected output? Also, your sample html doesn't have a `<div>` so it's unclear what `StockPage` looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first post. So i just want to narrow down the parse tree to make it easy overlooked. Atleast that was my approach to make it more comprehensive. Inside this div there is another div and another et cetera. so i got to the point where i find my text i want and try to take out. but for some reason this text is outside the span but inside the a tag. and i dont get how to take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text behind /span> "text"` are text nodes of `a tag` . So You have to select [a class="ellipsis" ] then you can call `.get_text()` method to get text nodes value as text/string

```
html='''
<html>
 <body>
  <a class="ellipsis" href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/5246/investor-a">
   <span class="flag small SE">
   </span>
   Investor A
  </a>
  <a class="ellipsis" href="/aktier/om-aktien.html/5247/investor-b">
   <span class="flag small SE">
   </span>
   Investor B
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

#print(soup.prettify())

for span in soup.find_all('a',class_="ellipsis"):
    txt = span.get_text(strip=True)
    print(txt)
```

**Output:**

```
Investor A
Investor B
```